# Error after Spring Security update form 3.1 to 3.2.1

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have update my spring security from 3.1 to 3.2.1 in maven/pom.xml. And I am using spring "3.1.0" version After updating i am getting the following error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 54 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was resolved in latest spring security version 3.2.2. If you want to resolve this error by using the same version then add maven dependencies for "spring-web".

Please refer " https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10218 " for further details. This is where i found the solution